# Finding a subdivision of $K_4$ in a graph with minimum degree $3$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In the Bondy and Murty's graph theory book there is the following exercise.

> Let $G$ be a nontrivial simple graph with $\delta(G)\geq 3$ or a vertex $v\in V(G)$ such that $\delta(G-v)\geq 3$. Then $G$ has a subdivision of $K_4$.

There, $\delta(G)$ denotes minimum degree.

There are some remarks to do: First, we can reduce the cases to the first one: $\delta(G)\geq 3$. If $d(v)<3$ we can take an edge $e$ such that $v\in e$ and by induction on $|G|$, $G/e$ has a subdivision of $K_4$, so $G$ also has one. We can also suppose $G$ is connected since we can also use induction on its components. We can also suppose $G$ is planar since both $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ have subdivisions of $K_4$.

The first thing I tried to do was check (as stated above) that we could suppose $G$ was planar, but my last attempt was checking the connectedness of the graph as follows:

If $G$ is connected, has $\delta(G)\geq 3$ and is not $2-$connected, then take a cut-vertex $v$ and a component $C$ of $G-v$. Then the induced subgraph of $C\cup v$ has at most one vertex of degree $<3$ (the cut-vertex), and by induction we're done. So we can suppose $G$ is $2-$connected. If we can reduce the case to one on which $G$ is $3-$connected then any $3$ vertices are in a common cycle, and then we can apply the Fan Lemma or Menger Theorem appropiately to get the subdivision of $K_4$ (It will be a cycle of length at least $3$ not covering all the vertices and a $3-$fan from one of the remaining vertices to that cycle).

> **The Fan Lemma**.
>   Let $G$ be a $k-$connected graph, let $x$ be a vertex of $G$, and let $Y ⊆ V -\{x\}$ be a set
>   of at least $k$ vertices of $G$. Then there exists a $k-$fan in G from $x$ to $Y$.

So we're left with the case where $G$ is $2-$connected but there is a separating set $S$ with $|S|=2$. But I wasn't able to conclude anything in this case. Is there anything we can do here? If we add the hypothesis of being planar here can it help?

Edit:

As Misha comments, there is a hole in the reasoning when we want to remove a vertex of degree $2$. The graph:
[image]

becomes

[image]

when contracting an edge incident to the degree-$2$ vertex, and in that case we get, not one, but two new vertices of degree $2$. We can still solve it: When we have a cut vertex $v$, we just take a connected component of $G-v$ with no vertex of $G$ of degree two.

Comment: As I was looking for holes in my argument, I found an (easily fixed) hole in yours. We can't necessarily contract an edge to get rid of a degree-$2$ vertex $v$, because we wouldn't get a simple graph when the neighbors of $v$ are already adjacent. Instead, we deal with both cases at once, and in your induction step (which is invoked when $G$ has a cut vertex) you want to choose $C$ to be a component with no degree-$2$ vertices.

Comment: The definition of contraction I've been using makes sure the contraction is still a simple graph (So candidates for multiple edges are identified). 

But it's still an hole because like that I could still get another vertex of degree $2$, and not only one, but possibly two. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I hope you didn't miss my suggestion for how to fix this? (Your edit makes that unclear.)

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ has a separating set $S = \{v,w\}$. Let $C$ be the smallest component of $G-S$ that doesn't have any vertices of degree $\le 2$ in $G$, and assume that $S$ is chosen to make $C$ as small as possible.

This, in particular, means that each of $v$ and $w$ has at least two neighbors in $C$. If, say, $w$ has only one neighbor $w'$ in $C$, then $S' = \{v,w'\}$ is another separating set of size $2$, and one of the components of $G-S'$ is $C-\{w'\}$, which is smaller than $C$. (And $C - \{w'\}$ cannot be empty, because then $w'$ would have had degree $\le 2$.)

Also, assuming $G$ is $2$-connected, there is a path connecting $v$ and $w$ outside $C$. Let $x$ be a neighbor of $v$ outside $C$; deleting $v$ should leave a path from $x$ to $C$, which must go through $w$.

Now create a new graph $G'$ in which all vertices outside $C \cup S$ are deleted, and we add a new edge $vw$ if it did not exist already. In $G'$, $v$ and $w$ still have degree at least $3$, and the degrees in $C$ are unchanged.

By induction, $G'$ contains a subdivision of $K_4$. This can be turned into a subdivision of $K_4$ in $G$: if the edge $vw$ is needed and not present in $G$, we can replace it by a path from $v$ to $w$ outside $C$, which we know exists.

---

Alternatively, if you're willing to use some powerful classification results similar to your observation about planar graphs, then you can start from the fact that the graphs with no subdivision of $K_4$ are precisely the [series-parallel graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph).

A series-parallel graph must have a vertex of degree $2$. More precisely, a series-parallel graph with source $s$ and sink $t$ either has no other vertices, or else has a vertex of degree $2$ other than $s$ and $t$. To prove this, you can verify that this property is preserved under both series composition and parallel composition:

- A series composition of two $K_2$s results in a path on $3$ vertices, which creates a vertex of degree $2$ other than $s$ and $t$. A parallel composition of two $K_2$s creates a multigraph, so it's not allowed.
- In a series or parallel composition of two graphs, at least one of which has three or more vertices, one of the graphs already had a vertex of degree $2$ other than $s$ and $t$. That vertex still has degree $2$ after the composition.

Therefore a graph with minimum degree $3$ cannot be series-parallel, so it has a subdivision of $K_4$.

We can refine this argument to also rule out graphs in which only one vertex has degree less than $2$. If our series and parallel composition involved at least two graphs with three or more vertices at any point, then each of them had an internal vertex of degree $2$. If not, then $s$ and $t$ can each have degree at most $2$: their degrees increase only with parallel compositions, and we can't parallel-compose a $2$-vertex graph with itself, so for $s$ or $t$ to reach degree $3$, we'd need two larger graphs.

Comment: In the first part when $vw$ is an edge, why are there five edges out of $S$?  If there were two components since $\delta(G)\geq 3$ there would be at least four edges (since $vw$ would count to both the degrees of $v$ and $w$) but I am not sure we can say there are at least five.

Comment: Okay, that was false, but we don't actually need it, because we can make use of the "one vertex is allowed to have smaller degree" thing.

Comment: I think there may be more vertices than $x$ which end up having degree less than $3$ when the contraction is done, for example, vertices in a component, of degree $3$, being adjacent to both $v,w$.

Consider the following graph: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-7fzw5mEqCwY/XBLSWnzCgFI/AAAAAAAADUc/kLnHOp7x88IgZjfgO-ZK7AqXs1Fi_cvYQCLcBGAs/s640/Sin%2Bt%25C3%25ADtulo.png

Of course, there is still a subdivision of $K_4$ there.

Comment: That's embarrassing! Sorry. I will try to fix the new mistake.

Comment: I'll also keep trying.

Comment: @DavidMolano Hopefully the new solution works. The argument is a bit simpler, so I feel more confident that there's no mistake, but I've been wrong twice so far...

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry if this is trivial. In the first line how do you know there is a component that doesn't have any vertex of degree less than equal to 2.

Comment: @abc It took me a while to understand what I was doing, but what that line means is that there is a component with no vertices which have degree $\le 2$ in $G$. That holds simply because there's at most one such vertex in $G$, and many components. (I've edited to clarify, since looking back my first read was probably the same as yours - that it means degree $\le 2$ in the component.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks! And can you please explain why "Also, assuming G is 2-connected, there is a path connecting v and w outside C. " is true? Are you using Mengers theorem somehow?

Comment: The next sentence is an explanation. All we need here is that $G-v$ must still be connected, so $G-v$ has an $x-w$ path (which we can turn into a $v-w$ path outside $C$).